# PHP Unset Array value effect on other indexes

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I am working with a PHP loop, and I had one question regarding how unset affects the array keys. This array uses the standard numeric keys assigned by PHP, `0, 1, 2, 3 etc...`. Whenever `unset()` runs on an array value, are the array keys shuffled or are they maintained as before?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is something you could have trivially tried out yourself...

Comment: He could have tried himself, but now this question is cemented here which is important to for simple unset google searches. It definitely helped me, so I thank you Oliver.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly That's not the first time SO has taken the place of documentation/trivial examples. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The keys are not shuffled or renumbered.  The `unset()` key is simply removed and the others remain.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
unset($a[2]);
print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: @Michael can we remove specific values from array like `4` with only single with `unset() `

Comment: @Rafee Do you mean to remove multiple values with one `unset()`? If so, you could use `array_diff()` to return a new array without the values you wanted removed.

Answer (score 3):

Test it yourself, but here's the output.

```
php -r '$a=array("a","b","c"); print_r($a); unset($a[1]); print_r($a);'
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [2] => c
)
```

Answer (score 2):

They are as they were. That one key is JUST DELETED

Answer (score 2):

The Key Disappears, whether it is numeric or not.  Try out the test script below.

```
<?php
    $t = array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
    foreach($t as $k => $v)
        echo($k . ": " . $v . "<br/>");
    // Output: 0: a, 1: b, 2: c, 3: d

    unset($t[1]);

    foreach($t as $k => $v)
        echo($k . ": " . $v . "<br/>");
    // Output: 0: a, 2: c, 3: d
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit out of context but in unsetting values from a global array, apply the answer by Michael Berkowski above but in use with `$GLOBALS` instead of the the global value you declared with `global $variable_name`. So it will be something like:

`unset($GLOBALS['variable_name']['array_key']);`

Instead of:

`global $variable_name;
unset($variable_name['array_key']);`

**NB**: This works only if you're using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

The keys are maintained with the removed key  missing but they can be rearranged by doing this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
unset($array[2]);
$arranged = array_values($array);
print_r($arranged);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)
```

Notice that if we do the following without rearranging:

```
unset($array[2]);
$array[]=3;
```

The index of the value 3 will be 5 because it will be pushed to the end of the array and will not try to check or replace missing index. This is important to remember when using FOR LOOP with index access.