# PHP unset Behavior

Tags: php

I came across some PHP behavior that **I** think is subtle, but pretty cool. But I don't understand how...

```
$test=array('a'=>'c', 'b'=>'c');
unset($test['a']);
var_dump($test);
```

This prints

```
array(1) { ["b"]=> string(1) "c" }
```

I would have expected the array to be emptied out. After all, **$test['a']** evaluates to 'c' so the unset function only sees 'c' but knows it was just the first 'c' value I wanted removing?

My guess is the interpeter is super smart and looks inside the array inside the parameter given to it - but that's purely conjecture ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376702/php-unset-array-value

Comment: I don't follow your logic in what you were expecting.  You unset a specific array key.  Why would `b=>c` be gone?

Comment: @Brad OP expected that PHP first interprets `$test['a']` which hold the value of `'c'` and then performs a removal of ALL identical values.

Comment: @Jack, Oh, that makes sense!  I understand now.  I think I've been looking at PHP too long when stuff like that makes sense.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, I did actually look at that question before posting (thanks to SO's helpful feature of showing related questing when you start typing) but no-one explained the WHY - but Kolink below's made it clear now - of course, just use pass by ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, no. `unset` is not a function, it is a language construct. Therefore it doesn't necessarily follow the same rules.

In this case, however, it actually works similarly to a pass-by-reference. It takes the reference to the variable, and destroys it.

Comment: it does take by ref and more cause the data structure of php vars within its source may be more pointers than whats seen.

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually doing is destroying (unsetting) the key "a" from the array `$test`. So after that key is destroyed, only "b" exists in the array.

If you wanted to remove all values of 'c' from the array, use [array_diff()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).